# Netbeans for production environment?

Tags: java, netbeans

Let me preface this by saying I have no knowledge of Java. I am working with someone who is using `Netbeans` for a production environment on one of his applications. I did some research on it and I was under the impression that `Netbeans` was (mainly) used as a Java testing environment.

Is my understand here correct, and he shouldn't be using Netbeans, or am I missing what the program/IDE is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans is an IDE (integrated development environment) - you use it for writing, testing and debugging code (essentially writing applications.)

If he's working on the application then Netbeans is a perfectly normal and good thing for him to be using (IDE wars aside!)

By production environment, do you mean he's working on an application in production or he's, for instance, running a production Java web service through Netbeans? The latter would indeed be a bit odd, but the former perfectly normal.

Since you state you have no knowledge of Java, my instinct reaction is to say leave him be, or perhaps just get him to explain the process to you. If he's using Netbeans properly then he most likely understands what he's doing.

Comment: The production service is being run on Netbeans.

Comment: What is the production service? A Desktop application? If so, he is using the Netbeans Platform, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @David542 What exactly is the production service? And is it being actively launched through Netbeans or is it just hooking into it to provide debug messages?

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is both a famous open-source [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and a [Software Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/). Nothing wrong with the IDE and the platform is certainly production ready.

Here's a [link](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/showcase.html) for the official Netbeans Platform Showcase, which includes several Mission Critical examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's doesn't matter if he uses Netbeans or another IDE for production builds. Because IDE is for development purposes.

What an IDE is for is to help developers write faster code by providing Autocomplete, refactoring and other plugin capabilities. Personal note I have used Netbeans before but I shifted away to Eclipse since it provided better support and as for Swing interfaces there is a nifty little plugin called [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) from Google.

Main thing I love about this GUI builder plugin is that it provides no .form file(A file Netbeans keeps when we make a Visual Component). You can edit the code as you want to in WindowBuilder.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I did some research on it and I was under the impression that Netbeans was (mainly) used as a Java testing environment.

It is one it's use, yes. But I know a lot of people using it for web applications. It does great in php and has support for all major web base languages. As those languages are natively supported they can be used easily for production environment.

There are also a lot of pluggins, like [python's](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81) wich is not natively supported. I wouldn't recommend the use of any community pluggins for production environment. Only the one that have passed quality control of netbeans developers are ok for sensitive work.

Answer (score 0):

I had no previous knowledge of Java and I used Netbeans IDE and there's no problem with it :)

It's good for both coding and testing and has a GUI Swing builder too!!

IDE stands for integrated ***DEVELOPMENT*** environment